# Ubuntu 20.04 graphics problems with AMD R9 380

Tags: drivers, graphics

Just installed Ubuntu 20.04 as a dual boot with Windows 10. When I ran the installer from a USB drive, I got a black screen until I rebooted and chose the "safe graphics" (I think that's what it was called anyway) option. This gave me a low-res display that was fine to install.

Now that the install is complete, on booting I again get a black screen. I can get past this by adding the `nomodeset` option. With this I get something on screen, but it's low resolution and quite terrible.

It seems that there is a driver problem with my AMD Radeon R9 380 card. The additional drivers tool doesn't offer me anything to install.

Details of my machine:
https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=a7b4c49c2a

Comment: "add the amdgpu.dc=0 kernel option," when you say this do you mean the grub boot menu? ^ Sorry I could not ask it in a comment because I do not have 50 points

Comment: Yes, that's what I did.

Answer (score 1):

I had fought this for hours before posting my question, and then found the solution minutes afterwards.

All I had to do was add the `amdgpu.dc=0` kernel option, and it now seems to work. I'm not really sure why this is needed, though.