# Xubuntu installation: "ERROR atombios stuck in loop for more than 5secs"

Tags: boot, grub2, usb, xubuntu

I am trying to install Xubuntu 20.04 from a Live USB prepared with the Startup Disk utility.
When I boot from it, the Xubuntu logo appears and the USB check is performed.

Once the check says OK, the screen stays the same for about a minute and then suddendly the logs appear with an error:

> ...
>  [  190.290327] kernel: [drm:atom_op_jump [radeon]] *ERROR*
> atombios stuck in loop for more than 5secs aborting 
>  [
> 190.290351] kernel: [drm:atom_execute_table_locked [radeon]] *ERROR* atombios stuck executing D1F6 (len 62, WS 0, PS 0) @ 0xD212 
>  ...

At this point, the boot does not advance and continues to print the same error again and again.

I read a post with a similar issue. It suggested to add a GRUB option:

*amdgpu.dc=0*

However, I am a complete newbie on this kind of things. Where should I add that line? Is it the right thing to do? Consider that I am still trying to boot from the USB for installing the OS.

My computer is a HP Envy 17 Notebook PC bought in 2010.
I already have Ubuntu 18.04 installed.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: pls tell us where you found the suggestion

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231188/ubuntu-20-04-graphics-problems-with-amd-r9-380. This post describes a problem quite similar to mine. Except that with Xubuntu I am not even able to approach the "Safe graphics" part because the boot crashes before. I also tried with Lubuntu 20.04 and in that case I was able to choose the "Try with Safe graphics"  and the boot went (mostly) smooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

very early in the boot process you get a screen with this symbol:

[image] at the lower bottom of the screen.

If you the press any key you will get to this:

[image]

Select your preffered language, and you will get to this screen:

[image]

Here you can either select one of the `safe graphic` modes or you could press <kbd>F6</kbd> followed by <kbd>Esc</kbd> and there will appear the `Boot Options` on the screen.

Now you can enter the boot option - **¡ other than in the picture, the correct option is `radeon.runpm=0` !** - so it will look (something) like this:

[image]

Hit <kbd>enter</kbd> and off you go!

P.S: You can change the boot option for any of the first 4 entries.

Comment: Right now I don't see the language page. I will try pressing any key when the first symbol appears as you suggested. I thought it should have appeared automatically as in Lubuntu. I will let you know.

Comment: You get the first symbol - right? you are not using an usb-keyboard on your laptop, because sometimes it takes a while for usb-devices to be recognized. - do you get to page after the language one?

Comment: As you said, I needed to click when the first symbol appeared. From there I was able to follow you answer. Instead of `amdgpu.dc=0`, I inserted `radeon.runpm=0` and the boot started working as intended. Thank you.

Comment: okay so I'll change the setting in the answer